# How to detect when vue component is after update function by property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to display a spinner in vue for **every** component (this is the requirement).

For that I think about to do `v-if="loading"` inside component HTML.

My question is how to detect when component is loading complete? (meaning after the DOM is rendered, and the data-bind is resolved to the DOM elements)

According to [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) when `update` function is trigger then the render is complete.

So for that I'll need to implement for **every component** `update` function that change the `loading` to `false`. is there eazy way to do that? for example one place to write the `update` function? can I do that without implement `extends`? any sophisticated way to do that?

What I need for example is `this.loading` available in Vue instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it. [Vue mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) come in rescue.

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for
> Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When
> a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed”
> into the component’s own options.

**Notice** that you should use [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook if you want to track when the component is inserted into DOM.

> Called after the instance has been mounted, where `el` is replaced by
> the newly created `vm.$el`. If the root instance is `mounted` to an
> in-document element, `vm.$el` will also be in-document when mounted is
> called.

`mixin.js`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('I have been mounted')
    this.loading = false
  }
}
```

And then register that mixin globally, so it will be available in all components:

```js
import mixin from './mixin'

Vue.mixin(mixin)
```

Comment: One more thing please: Is there a way to know when all the children components are rendered(after mounted)? for example I have Person component, and I have children (not by v-for) and I want to know from Person component when the children is ready and rendered. there is a way to do that?

Comment: Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use `vm.$nextTick` inside of mounted. [ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).